# Set a macro to check if the links in a relative column are active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a filtered table where I need change the contents of the last column to check if the link in the second to last column is active. So a have set a personalized script to check the links, which works fine.

My problem is that I want to set up a macro that fills the whole filtered column with a formula that triggers the checking function and I havent been able. Since the columns before this will change I'm trying to make it a relative range, both for the links being checked and the formula.

My current working macro, with variables not being used, is:

```
function CheckLinks() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var filtro = (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getFilter().getRange());
  var row = filtro.getRow()+1;
  var lastRow = filtro.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = filtro.getLastColumn();
  spreadsheet.getRange('U2').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();


  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: false});
  spreadsheet.getRange('U2').activate()
  .setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(T2);"Not found";checkStatus(T2))');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('U2:U'+lastRow), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
};
```

For some reason, I get an error when with getRange(2,21) instead of ('U2'), nevermind using getRange(row,lastcolumn).

I want it to fill the whole lastColumn with the formula, and I haven't even tried to make the formula itself work with a variable.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My problem is that I want to set up a macro that fills the whole filtered column with a formula that triggers the checking function and I havent been able. Since the columns before this will change I'm trying to make it a relative range, both for the links being checked and the formula.`. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: No problem, english is my second language so I may not be so clear. I have a filter where the las two columns are a link and a formula that says if the link works. Columns and rows in the filter will change, be added and deleted, but this two columns will stay the same. I want to set up a macro that erases and refills the last column with the formula, but relative to the filter, not as absolute ranges/values.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I managed to solve it. I'll be posting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer after deep diving on the apps script reference. Apparently, by using the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet` I couldn't reference the row and column by number, only by A1 notation. I had to change it to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet`. That way I could make the variables work and get the rows and columns relative to the filter, so any changes I make will still reference the last rows. I also used `getA1Notation` to insert the first reference cell into the formul a and have the autofill do the rest. So it ended up looking like this:

```
function Checklinks() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var filter = (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getFilter().getRange());
  var row = filter.getRow()+1; //*to get the firt data row, not the headers*//
  var lastCol = filter.getLastColumn()-1; //*Column with the formula*//
  var linkCol = filter.getLastColumn()-2; //*Column with the links*//
  var startCell = spreadsheet.getRange(row,lastCol); //*First cell with formula*//
  var rowTot = filter.getNumRows()-1; //*To get the number of cells to Autofill*//
  var linkCell = spreadsheet.getRange(row,linkCol).getA1Notation();
   //*To get the working notation of first cell of the links to the formula*//
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell(); 

  //*To clear the current formula*//
  startCell.activate();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: false});
  //*To set the formula again*//
  startCell.activate()
  .setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK('+linkCell+');"Not found";checkStatus('+linkCell+'))');
  //*Filling the column, including the new rows*//
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange(row,lastCol,rowTot), 
  SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
};
```